# What's the physical appearance of Dragonborns?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonborn

I'm looking for a miniature for my Dragonborn fighter. I know the basics but I haven't really find anything definite about the the little details, like the shape of the legs and if they have tails.

Comment: Have you checked the book featuring the dragonborn race you're using for details and illustrations? (I know I posted this on the other question that you deleted and you probably saw it, but I might as well post it here too on the one still remaining.) This is one of those things you should comment on to establish whether you've done your research first, and what has you still confused if you've already done it.

Comment: This is still a duplicate and should not be reopened.